# While readLine() != null loop from BufferedReader created from socket InputStream never exits

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, bufferedreader

Im reading the input line by line from a socket `InputStream` using a `BufferedReader` but nothing after the while loop seems to get executed. The socket is coming from `accept()` on `ServerSocket` not from something like this `Socket link = new Socket(address, 80);`.

#### Code

```
        String input;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        DataOutputStream out = null;
        boolean foundConnectionHeader = false;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            // Change keep alive connection header to close, add connection header if it doesn't exist
            while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (foundConnectionHeader) {
                    requestHeaders.add(input);
                } else {
                    if (input.contains("Proxy-Connection: keep-alive")) {
                        requestHeaders.add("Proxy-Connection: close");
                        foundConnectionHeader = true;
                    } else {
                        requestHeaders.add(input);
                    }
                }
//              System.out.println(input);
            }
            if (!foundConnectionHeader) {
                requestHeaders.add("Proxy-Connection: close");
            }
            
            System.out.println("DONE");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will return null when the peer disconnects.

If you're going to implement HTTP you need a good knowledge of RFC 2616, especially the parts about content length and connection lifetime. Your present code doesn't begin to be adequate.

Comment: How can I get all the header information and then exit the loop? I would like to read the request from the client up to the blank line. Could I do while `input.length > 0`?

Comment: Yes, but then you have another problem, as there will be data buffered in the buffered reader and you need to switch to an input stream at this point, as the payload may not be character data. This means you shouldn't use a buffered reader at all, you need to use an input stream for everything and figure out your own read-line code.

Comment: Lets say I was only concerned with GET and POST requests, wouldn't the header fields of these request always be guaranteed to be character data? The body of these methods would contain the non character byte data, no?

Comment: That's what I said. The payload after the blank line isn't guaranteed to be character data.